# error in multilingual code

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual

this is my code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://jquery-translate.googlecode.com/files/jquery.translate-1.3.7.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($) { //when DOM is ready

       // $('body').css('height', '100px');


        $.translate(function() {  //when the Google Language API is loaded

            function translateTo(destLang) { //this can be declared in the global scope too if you need it somewhere else
               // alert('lang' + destLang);

                $('body').translate('english', destLang, {   //translate from english to the selected language
                    not: '.jq-translate-ui',  //by default the generated element has this className
                    fromOriginal: true   //always translate from english (even after the page has been translated)
                });
            }


            //you can generate other controls as well, not just a dropdown:
            $.translate.ui('ul', 'li', 'span')
      .appendTo('body')    //insert the element to the page
      .css({ 'color': 'blue', 'background-color': 'white' })
      .find('span')
      .css('cursor', 'pointer')
      .click(function() {   //when selecting another language

          translateTo($(this).text());

          //$.cookie('destLang', $(this).text());
          // set a cookie to remember the selected language
          // see: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

          return false; //prevent default browser action
      });



             var destLang = $.cookie('destLang'); //get previously translated language

            if (destLang)  //if it was set then
                translateTo(destLang);


        }); //end of Google Language API loaded

    });  //end of DOM ready
</script>

I m getting error at line
    var destLang = $.cookie('destLang');
```

**error is :**

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires jQuery cookie plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: its done but i wanted to have only three or four languages like japanese, korian, etc. Currently i m getting all languages.